# Moving cards from Kanban board

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build this Custom Kanban (TODO) board from scratch (Vanilla JS, CSS, and no external libraries - jQuery is fine (preferred vanilla JS))

I'm currently stuck in a place where I'm trying to move cards from one row to another when user clicks on '>' (next) or '<' (previous). I'm not sure how to go about implementing something like this.

Here's my code: (Full page preferred)
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/rdabbir/pen/vYBxOYW)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
}

.board-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-left: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.board-column:last-child {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.todo {
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

.board-column > .board-column-header {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 36%;
  background: #333;
}

.board-column.todo .board-column-header {
  background: #4A9FF9;
}
.board-column.working .board-column-header {
  background: #f9944a;
}
.board-column.done .board-column-header {
  background: #2ac06d;
}

.board-column.backlog .board-column-header {
  background: red;
}

.board-column-content {
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  min-height: 95px;
}

.board-item {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.board-item-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff; /* White */
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.next {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  height: 21px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.prev {
  float: left;
  height: 21px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <section class="board-column todo">
    <section class="board-column-header"> TODO </section>
    <section class="board-column-content">
       <div class="board-item">
         <div class="board-item-content">
           <span>Item #</span>1<button class="action next"> > </button></div></div>
       <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content"><span>Item #</span>2<button class="action next"> > </button></div></div>
             <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content"><span>Item #</span>3<button class="action next"> > </button></div></div>
    </section>
  </section>
  
  <section class="board-column todo working">
    <section class="board-column-header"> Working </section>
    <section class="board-column-content">
       <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content">
         <button class="action prev"> < </button>
         <span>Item #</span>4<button class="action next"> > </button></div></div>
       <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> < </button><span>Item #</span>5<button class="action next"> > </button></div></div>
             <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> < </button><span>Item #</span>6<button class="action next"> > </button></div></div>
    </section>
  </section>
  
  <section class="board-column todo done">
    <section class="board-column-header"> Done </section>
    <section class="board-column-content">
       <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> < </button><span>Item #</span>7<button class="action next"> > </button></div></div>
       <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> < </button><span>Item #</span>8<button class="action next"> > </button></div></div>
             <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> < </button><span>Item #</span>9<button class="action next"> > </button></div></div>
    </section>
  </section>
  
    <section class="board-column todo backlog">
    <section class="board-column-header"> Backlog </section>
    <section class="board-column-content">
       <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> < </button><span>Item #</span>10</div></div>
       <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> < </button><span>Item #</span>11</div></div>
             <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> < </button><span>Item #</span>12</div></div>
    </section>
  </section>
  
</article>
```

How do I move cards from tow A to next
row when user clicks on '>' (next) or '<' (previous)?

Can I make any optimizations for my current code to make it more readable?

Comment: Q1: easy, just change it's position in the DOM. That should move it on screen. I.e. you'll be manipulating the DOM children of article.container. If you don't know what the DOM is (I'm assuming you do) then you have some reading to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that I can take the DOM and do something like 'appendTo' but my  question is . How can I change it exactly in the same position? (I.e the row1 col2 element should be exactly in row2 col2). Would very much appreciate more inputs (or code)

Comment: @RichardBarker ^^

Comment: I get that it's a matrix, but the logic is the same just in 2d. You need to track the column & row index in the DOM -- look into `data-` attributes for that.

Comment: Umm not sure how data- attributes can help. Kinda lost! I'm currently trying to think through an approach of getting the child number in the parent's row. And then go to the next immediate parent and then use `Node.insertBefore` to append it to next parent.

Comment: You're getting there... The attributes will store the row and column; you can add them dynamically, and mutate them. Your buttons will grab the data attributes you need, and then place the item where it needs to go. The attributes give you your x and y, your buttons tell you whether to add 1 or subtract 1 from whichever you designate the column.

Answer (score 1):

Logic overview:

- Find the item containing the button
- Find the column containing that item
- Find either next or previous column after that, depending on direction
- Insert the item into that column's item list

As for structure, I wouldn't say it's too bad - one change I made was making it so that every item has previous/next buttons, but they are hidden via CSS where appropriate.

```js
function findParentWithClass(el, className) {
  while (el && !el.classList.contains(className)) {
    el = el.parentElement;
  }
  return el;
}
function getElementChildIndex(el) {
  let i = 0;
  while (el = el.previousElementSibling) i++;
  return i;
}
function swapClick(btn, dir) {
  let item = findParentWithClass(btn, "board-item");
  let sct1 = findParentWithClass(item, "board-column");
  let sct2 = dir > 0 ? sct1.nextElementSibling : sct1.previousElementSibling;
  if (!sct2) return;
  //
  let dest = sct2.querySelector('.board-column-content');
  let pos = getElementChildIndex(item);
  dest.insertBefore(item, dest.children[pos]);
}
for (let el of document.getElementsByClassName('prev')) {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => swapClick(el, -1));
}
for (let el of document.getElementsByClassName('next')) {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => swapClick(el, 1));
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
}

.board-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-left: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.board-column:last-child {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.todo {
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

.board-column > .board-column-header {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 36%;
  background: #333;
}

.board-column.todo .board-column-header {
  background: #4A9FF9;
}
.board-column.working .board-column-header {
  background: #f9944a;
}
.board-column.done .board-column-header {
  background: #2ac06d;
}

.board-column.backlog .board-column-header {
  background: red;
}

.board-column-content {
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  min-height: 95px;
}

.board-item {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.board-item-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff; /* White */
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.next {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  height: 21px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.prev {
  float: left;
  height: 21px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.board-column:first-child .action.prev { display: none }
.board-column:last-child .action.next { display: none }
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <section class="board-column todo">
    <section class="board-column-header"> TODO </section>
    <section class="board-column-content">
      <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content">
          <button class="action prev"> &lt; </button>
          <span>Item #</span>1
          <button class="action next"> &gt; </button>
      </div></div>
      <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content">
          <button class="action prev"> &lt; </button>
          <span>Item #</span>2
          <button class="action next"> &gt; </button>
      </div></div>
      <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content">
          <button class="action prev"> &lt; </button>
          <span>Item #</span>3
          <button class="action next"> &gt; </button>
      </div></div>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="board-column todo working">
    <section class="board-column-header"> Working </section>
    <section class="board-column-content">
      <div class="board-item">
        <div class="board-item-content">
          <button class="action prev"> &lt; </button>
          <span>Item #</span>4
          <button class="action next"> &gt; </button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="board-item">
        <div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> &lt; </button><span>Item #</span>5
          <button class="action next"> &gt; </button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="board-item">
        <div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> &lt; </button><span>Item #</span>6
          <button class="action next"> &gt; </button></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="board-column todo done">
    <section class="board-column-header"> Done </section>
    <section class="board-column-content">
      <div class="board-item">
        <div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> &lt; </button><span>Item #</span>7
          <button class="action next"> &gt; </button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="board-item">
        <div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> &lt; </button><span>Item #</span>8
          <button class="action next"> &gt; </button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="board-item">
        <div class="board-item-content"><button class="action prev"> &lt; </button><span>Item #</span>9
          <button class="action next"> &gt; </button></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="board-column todo backlog">
    <section class="board-column-header"> Backlog </section>
    <section class="board-column-content">
      <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content">
        <button class="action prev"> &lt; </button>
        <span>Item #</span>10
        <button class="action next"> &gt; </button>
      </div></div>
      <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content">
        <button class="action prev"> &lt; </button>
        <span>Item #</span>11
        <button class="action next"> &gt; </button>
      </div></div>
      <div class="board-item"><div class="board-item-content">
        <button class="action prev"> &lt; </button>
        <span>Item #</span>12
        <button class="action next"> &gt; </button>
      </div></div>
    </section>
  </section>

</article>
```

Comment: This is awesome. thank you so much @YellowAfterlife however, only one question. It seems like we are prepending the card at the bottom of the next row. How can we move and maintain the exact position in the next row?

Comment: There seems to be another bug in the implementation. The right arrow button should be hidden once the card moves to the extreme right (must have a left arrow button)

Comment: Added a snip for maintaining order - you calculate the index of element inside container and then use it for picking position in other container. On arrows, note that I had also updated HTML to have both arrows in every item and then hid the arrows in first/last element using CSS.